# HTML dropdown options are wider than button

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

Firstly I am pretty certain it is not a problem with the options having padding/margin/border as I've specifically set them to have none.

To see the problem please go here: http://antemortem.thecomicseries.com/comics/last
Scrolling down bellow the image is a HTML dropdown menu with 'Page 1' on it. Clicking on this there are a few other options, and to the right there is an extra maybe 15px of menu which I simply cannot understand. It can't be clicked on like the options, it isn't supposed to be there and it makes the options width greater than 180px which is what it's set to be.

PLEASE NOTE, I HAVE TESTED TO SEE IF THIS GREY SPACE APPEARS ON CHROME AND OPERA, AND IT DOESN'T.
This leads me to believe it only appears only on Firefox...

To see the code please just inspect the element as it will probably be easier for you to investigate, but if not I can past the HTML/CSS in.

So basically I just want the extra grey space gone, so that the options are no wider than the dropdown menu button itself.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head>
  <!-- Last Update: 23/05/2013 -->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="/rss/">
  <title>Ante Mortem | Page 1</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   #bottomnav {
margin-top: 10px;
}

.authorname {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

.posttime {
padding-left: 10px;
}

#authorcontrol {
margin-top: 30px;
}

.fallback {
display: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

.dropcon {
padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
height: 18px;
width: 184px;
border: 2px solid #400000;
border-bottom: 0px solid #000000;
background-color: #5F0000;
bottom: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#main {
font-weight: strong;

}

option, .comicnavlink {
text-align: center;
width: 180px;
margin: auto;
}

option {
width: 180px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

#comicnavigation {
height: 50px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#authorccontrol {
margin: auto;
}

.acheader {
  background-color: #4C0000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 780px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.acheaderreply {
  background-color: #4C0000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 740px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.accontent {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: 761px;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4C0000;
}

.accontent p {
  text-align: left;
}

.accontentreply {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  width: 721px;
  color: white;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
  border: 2px solid #4C0000;
}

.accontentreply p {
  text-align: left;
}

.acfooter {
  background-color: #4C0000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 775px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.acfooterreply {
  background-color: #4C0000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 735px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#controls {
  padding: 8px 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  clear: both;
  width: 184px;
  height: 115px;
  background: #5F0000;
  border: 2px solid #400000;
  border-top: 0px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  right: 2px;
}

html, body, #container {
height: 100%;
}

body > #container {
height: auto; min-height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 10px;
font-size: 62.5%;
font-family: lucida sans unicode, lucida grande, verdana, sans-serif;
color: #000000;
text-align: center;
min-width:650px;
background-image: url(http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/f/8/alpha_test4_by_nightspirit174-d60wfqz.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center bottom;
}

#container {
width: 800px;
margin: auto;
background-color: black;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #990000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #990000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #990000;
}

#headerimg {
cursor: pointer;
}

img {
border: 0px;
}

a {
color: #C84446;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
color: #44A4C8;
cursor: default;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
font-family: lucida grande, lucida sans unicode, verdana, sans-serif;
line-height: 1em !important;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#cf_ads {
 display:table;
 margin:7px auto;
 text-align:center;
}

#slogan {
 color:#BBB;
}

#navigation {
margin: 15px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-right:30px;
}

#nav {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li {
display: inline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav li a {
display: inline-block;
background: #6B0000;
padding: 15px;
margin: 1px;
font: 1.5em century gothic, lucida grande, verdana, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #6B0000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #6B0000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #6B0000;
}

#nav li a:hover {
color: black;
}

html>/**/body #wrap {/*hide from ie7 and below - they don't support display:table, so they get an actual table*/
margin: auto;
width: 720px;
display:table;
}

#wrapie {
margin: auto;
width: 720px;
}

#contentwrap {
margin: auto;
width: 780px;
text-align: center;
}

.comicnav {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline;
color: white;
list-style-type: none;
}

.comicnav td {
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.comicnav td img {
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px;
}

.comment, .permalinks {
margin-top: 10px;
background: #ffffff;
opacity: 0.95;
-moz-opacity: 0.95;
filter: alpha(opacity=95);
font: 1.2em lucida grande, lucida sans unicode, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.rating, .post {
margin-top: 5px;
background: #5F0000;
font: 1.5em lucida grande, lucida sans unicode, verdana, sans-serif;
}

#comments {
clear: both;
}

#authorcomments {
float: left;
}

.permalinks:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
-moz-opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

#saveplace {
padding-bottom: 5px;
font-size: 1.5em;
}

.comment {
min-height: 100px;
height: auto !important;
with: 550px
}

.authorcomment {
min-height: 100px;
height: auto !important;
width: 550px;
}

.reply {
margin-left: 40px;
}

.authorcommentreply {
width: 740px;
margin-left: 40px;
}

.rating, .post, .permalinks {
padding: 5px;
}

.commentheader {
background: #1B1B1B;
padding: 5px 5px 2px 5px;
color: #3d3d3d;
text-align: right;
}

.actioncomment {
text-align: left;
}

.avatar {
float: left;
margin: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}

h4 {
font-size: 0.9em;
color: #A3A3A3;
text-align: left;
}

h2, h3 {
font-size: 2em;
text-align: justify;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
color: #ffffff;
}

h2 a {
color: #ffffff;
}

.commentcontent {
padding: 2px 20px 5px 20px;
text-align: left;
min-height: 100px;
height:auto !important;
height: 100px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

h3 {
color: #1B1B1B;
}

.editdelete {
font-size: 1.3em;
}

#footer {
font: 0.9em lucida grande, lucida sans unicode, verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: black;
color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
clear: both;
padding: 20px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -2.5em;
margin-bottom: 5px;
width: 760px;
height: 2.5em;
box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #990000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #990000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #990000;
}

#content {
padding-bottom: 2.5em;
}

#title {
background: #1B1B1B;
opacity: 0.8;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
padding: 20px;
margin: 10px auto;
}

.commentheadings {
padding: 15px;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 500px;
}

h5 {
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 2.4em;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.textcontent {
background: #ffffff;
padding: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 1.3em;
text-align: left;
}

table {
font: 1.3em lucida sans unicode, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.textcontent h3 {
text-align: center !important;
}

.chaptertitle {
 background-color:#F0F0F0;
 text-align:center;
 color:#888;
}

.chaptertitle h3 {
 color:#555;
 text-size: 1em;
}

#searchbar {
 text-align:center;
}

#searchbar input {
 border:1px solid black;
 color:black;
 background-color:white;
}

#searchbar input.submit {
 background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

.center {
 text-align:center;
}

.permalinkcode {
 width:90%;
 border:1px solid black;
}

  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://www.comic-rocket.com/ping-XUTp.js?z=-1o&amp;s=1366x768x24&amp;c=e54q&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fantemortem.thecomicseries.com%2Fcomics%2Flast&amp;r=http%3A%2F%2Fantemortem.thecomicseries.com%2Fcomics%2Ffirst"></script><script src="http://www.comic-rocket.com/metrics.js#key=XUTp"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://comicfury.com/cflayoutjs.js.php?cc=inline&amp;wcid=14208"></script><style type="text/css">.cce { display:none; } .cce20103 { display:inline !important; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
(function(d,t,p){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.src='http'+(d.location.protocol=='https:'?'s':'')+'://www.comic-rocket.com/metrics.js#'+(p||"");s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
})(document,'script','key=XUTp');
</script>

<script>
$('#dropcon li ul').hide().removeClass('fallback');
$('#dropcon li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(1000);
    },
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(1000);
    }
);
</script>

 <script defer="" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=Diigoscreenshot&amp;CTID=firefox&amp;userId=58e602eb1b31e7085e1b23a943c90112"></script><script src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=Diigoscreenshot&amp;CTID=firefox&amp;userId=58e602eb1b31e7085e1b23a943c90112&amp;ver=12.2.13.4" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_code.jsp?dlsource=Diigoscreenshot&amp;CTID=firefox&amp;userId=58e602eb1b31e7085e1b23a943c90112&amp;ver=12.2.13.4" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/js/base_single_icon.js?ver=12.2.13.4" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/dojo/io/script.xd.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5.1/dojo/window.xd.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script><script charset="utf-8" id="sufioIoScript1" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/getSupportedSitesJSON.action?ver=6.1&amp;callback=SF_isURISupported" type="text/javascript"></script></head>

 <body>

<div id="container">
<div id="content">

<div id="header">
<a href="/comics/latest" id="headerimg"> 

<script>
image = new Array
image[1]="<img src='http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/096/f/e/untitled4_by_nightspirit174-d60m54s.png' width='800' height='215'/>"

var rand_no = Math.floor((2-1)*Math.random()) + 1;

document.write(image[rand_no]);
</script><img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/096/f/e/untitled4_by_nightspirit174-d60m54s.png" height="215" width="800">

</a>
</div>

<div id="navigation">

    <ul id="nav">

     <li><a href="/comics/first">First</a></li>
     <li><a href="/comics/last">Latest</a></li>
     <li><a href="/archive/">Archive</a></li>



        <li><a href="/search/">Search</a></li>


        <li><a href="http://comicfury.com/comic.php?action=addsubscription&amp;cid=14208">Subscribe</a></li>


    </ul>

</div>



   <div id="wrap">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
     <table id="wrapie"><tr><td>
    <![endif]-->




     <div id="title">
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
    <h4>Posted 23rd May 2013, 10:16 PM</h4>
</div>

<img src="http://antemortem.thecomicseries.com/images/comics/63/005330542900fd813a7400a7f9595ad023217482.png" alt="Page 1" title="Elizabeth roof alley climb crawl moon" id="comicimage">

<div id="contentwrap">
        <div id="comicnavigation">

    <table class="comicnav">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td><a href="/comics/1/" rel="start" title="First"><img src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/5/a/untitled2_by_nightspirit174-d60vejq.gif"></a></td>
    <td><a href="/comics/3" rel="prev" title="Previous"><img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/c/a/untitled4_by_nightspirit174-d60veno.gif"></a></td>

    <td><select onchange="jumpTo(this.options[selectedIndex].value);" class="comicnavlink">

              <option value="/comics/1/"> Prologue: Page 1</option>

              <option value="/comics/2/">Prologue: Page 2</option>

              <option value="/comics/3/">A Beginning and an End</option>

              <option value="/comics/4/" selected="selected">Page 1</option>

       </select></td>

    <td><a href="/comics/" rel="next" title="Next"><img src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/4/c/untitled3_by_nightspirit174-d60velo.gif"></a></td>
    <td><a href="/comics/" rel="index" title="Latest"><img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/8/7/untitled_by_nightspirit174-d60veg0.gif"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="dropcon">
    <div id="main">Post, Rate, Save &amp; Load</div>
    <div class="fallback">

          <div id="controls">
                <div id="saveplace">
                    <a href="#" onclick="savePlace(this,304223);return false;">Save My Place</a><br>
                    <a href="#" onclick="loadPlace();return false;">Load My Place</a>
                </div>

                <div class="rating">

                    Rate this page: 
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=1" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=1&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="1"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=2" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=2&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="2"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=3" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=3&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="3"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=4" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=4&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="4"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=5" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=5&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="5"></a>
                    <br>Average rating: <em>0</em>

                </div>

                <div class="post">
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com/leavecomment.php?id=304223" onclick="var cl = window.open('http://comicfury.com/leavecomment.php?id=304223', 'cw', 'height=400, width=500'); cl.focus(); return false;" title="post a comment">Post a comment</a>
                </div>     
    </div>


    </div>

    <script>
    $('.dropcon').hover(
        function () {
            $('.fallback', this).stop().slideDown(125);
        },
        function () {
            $('.fallback', this).stop().slideUp(125);
        }
    );
    </script>

    </div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>

        </div>
        <div id="authorcontrol">              

                <div class="authorcomment">
                       <div class="acheader">
                          <a href="http://comicfury.com/profile.php?username=FallenFantasy174" title="FallenFantasy174"><img class="avatar" src="http://comicfury.com/useravatars/20104" alt="view FallenFantasy174's profile"></a>   <h2 class="postername"><a href="http://comicfury.com/profile.php?username=FallenFantasy174" title="FallenFantasy174">FallenFantasy174</a></h2><br>
                          <h4 class="posttime">23rd May 2013, 10:16 PM</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="accontent">
                          <p>Wonder what she's up to? :P<br>
<br>
Sorry I didn't upload in time for wen I said I would, I was too busy and had to deal with stuff. :/<br>
<br>
Anyway I'm really happy with the lighting, layout and the sky in this one. I've also started to use MangaStudio as well as Gimp so this was done in a mixture of the two Unfortunately it takes a while to swap things between them but on the bright side there's alot MangaStudio can do that Gimp can't so I'm having fun with that. :P<br>
<br>
</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="acfooter">
                           <div class="cc cc20104">
                                <a href="http://comicfury.com/editcomment.php?id=518701" class="cce cce20104" onclick="var cw = window.open('http://comicfury.com/editcomment.php?id=518701', 'ce', 'height=400, width=500'); cw.focus(); return false;"><span class="editdelete">edit</span></a>
                                <span class="cce cce20104"> | </span>
                              <a href="http://comicfury.com/editcomment.php?delete=1&amp;id=518701" class="ccd ccd20104" onclick="var cw = window.open('http://comicfury.com/editcomment.php?delete=1&amp;id=518701', 'ce', 'height=400, width=500'); cw.focus(); return false;"><span class="editdelete">delete</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div id="comments">



<div id="bottomnav">

    <table class="comicnav">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td><a href="/comics/1/" rel="start" title="First"><img src="http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/5/a/untitled2_by_nightspirit174-d60vejq.gif"></a></td>
    <td><a href="/comics/3" rel="prev" title="Previous"><img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/c/a/untitled4_by_nightspirit174-d60veno.gif"></a></td>

    <td><select onchange="jumpTo(this.options[selectedIndex].value);" class="comicnavlink">

              <option value="/comics/1/"> Prologue: Page 1</option>

              <option value="/comics/2/">Prologue: Page 2</option>

              <option value="/comics/3/">A Beginning and an End</option>

              <option value="/comics/4/" selected="selected">Page 1</option>

       </select></td>

    <td><a href="/comics/" rel="next" title="Next"><img src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/4/c/untitled3_by_nightspirit174-d60velo.gif"></a></td>
    <td><a href="/comics/" rel="index" title="Latest"><img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/098/8/7/untitled_by_nightspirit174-d60veg0.gif"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="dropcon">
    <div id="main">Post, Rate, Save &amp; Load</div>
    <div class="fallback">

          <div id="controls">
                <div id="saveplace">
                    <a href="#" onclick="savePlace(this,304223);return false;">Save My Place</a><br>
                    <a href="#" onclick="loadPlace();return false;">Load My Place</a>
                </div>

                <div class="rating">

                    Rate this page: 
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=1" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=1&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="1"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=2" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=2&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="2"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=3" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=3&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="3"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=4" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=4&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="4"></a>
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=5" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://comicfury.com//ratecomic.php?id=304223&amp;vote=5&quot;,&quot;edit&quot;,&quot;menubar=no,width=500,height=400,toolbar=no&quot;); return false;"><img src="http://comicfury.com/images/layouts/vote-unselected.gif" alt="X" title="5"></a>
                    <br>Average rating: <em>0</em>

                </div>

                <div class="post">
                    <a href="http://comicfury.com/leavecomment.php?id=304223" onclick="var cl = window.open('http://comicfury.com/leavecomment.php?id=304223', 'cw', 'height=400, width=500'); cl.focus(); return false;" title="post a comment">Post a comment</a>
                </div>     
    </div>


    </div>

    <script>
    $('.dropcon').hover(
        function () {
            $('.fallback', this).stop().slideDown(125);
        },
        function () {
            $('.fallback', this).stop().slideUp(125);
        }
    );
    </script>

    </div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>

</div>

        </div>
</div>






    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
     </td></tr></table>
    <![endif]-->
   </div>

</div>
</div>

<!--footer-->
<div id="footer">
Hosted on <a href="http://comicfury.com">ComicFury</a> | Layout © <a href="-" title="whistleonwild">whistleonwild</a> &amp; Pirate | Background: ~NS~ <br>
Comic © 2013 - 2013 Aisling Allan. All rights reserved. <br>
<a href="/rss/">RSS</a> |

 <a href="http://comicfury.com/comicprofile.php?url=antemortem">Comic Profile</a> | 

<a href="#">Top</a><br>

</div>
<!--footer end -->



<sfmsg data="{&quot;imageCount&quot;:0,&quot;ip&quot;:&quot;1.1.1.1&quot;}" id="sfMsgId"></sfmsg></body></html>
```

Comment: Do you have any `padding` or `margin` set on it at all? Please post your code too so we can take a look.

Comment: tinyurl.com/so-debug Please paste the relevant code that causes the issue. Are you using a CSS reset ?

Comment: There is no padding or margin or border, as stated. I will edit the code in.

Okay will do. Not as far as I know but I don't know what that is...?

Comment: The code is now edited in my origional post.

Answer (score 0):

setting the width of the option helps big time, but to remove the line(this is the place reserved for the scrollbar I think) I think you'll need to make a custom select box... as for the width use:

```
.comicnavlink option {
    width: 160px;
}
```

Atleast on my screen this fixes it.

Comment: Ah, the scroll bar explains that, and yes changing the width to 160px works but it currently waists width having the space for a non-existent scroll bar, so how would I make a custom select box? Or at least what is one of them and I'll do my best to do it.

Comment: you can try this [one](https://github.com/sparkbox/Custom-Selectbox) or this [one](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) or simply try some [tutorials](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/06/20/create-a-custom-select-box-with-jquery/)